# Can the live CD repair boot problems?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, dell, 15.04

I would like to know if the live image of a Installation disk can be used to recover the system or Grub?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System should help